# Group scss and css files into one file with assetic

Tags: css, symfony, compass

In a Symfony2 project, I have several `css` and `scss` files. I use the `compass` filter to dump the `scss` ones and `cssrewrite` applied to all:

```
{% stylesheets 
filter='compass, cssrewrite'
'scssFile1.scss'
'scssFile2.scss' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}

{% stylesheets 
filter='cssrewrite'
'cssFile1.css'
'cssFile2.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

I want to group those files into one. I've tried:

```
{% stylesheets 
filter='compass, cssrewrite'
'scssFile1.scss'
'scssFile2.scss'
'cssFile1.css'
'cssFile2.css' %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

but I'm getting an error when doing `assetic:dump` because the `css` files have not the `scss` extension.
Is there any way to group `scss` and `css` files into one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to combine files with different extensions, you´ll need to specify it in the Assetic filters configuration, specifically the `apply_to` parameter . Try modifying like in [this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/apply_to_option.html#filtering-based-on-a-file-extension), in which they use regular expressions (so you can play around with it). For instance, to use .scss and .sass extensions:

```
assetic:
    filters:
        compass:
            apply_to:   "\.s[ac]ss$"
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thank you.