# Merge scss and css file into one with assetic

Tags: css, symfony, sass, assetic

I would like to know if it is possible to merge css and scss file into one. 
I use Symfony 2.7 and my config.yml look like this:

```
assetic:
    assets:
        main:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/morrisjs/morris.js/morris.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/*
            output: 'css/main.css'
            filters:
                - sass
                - cssrewrite
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
          bin: C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\sass
          apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

When I try to dump assets with

```
php app/console assetic:dump
```

I have an error with this because sass is trying to parse the css file. 
Why "apply_to" doesn't work ?

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30455028/group-scss-and-css-files-into-one-file-with-assetic) but it dosen't help me...

Comment: What is your error ? Post the error text ...

Comment: The error doesn't really matter, it's the same kind of error you get when you try to parse a css file with sass:
`'Error Output:
  WARNING on line 1 of C:\cygwin64\tmp\ass2DDF.tmp:
  This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
  WARNING on line 2 of C:\cygwin64\tmp\ass2DDF.tmp:
  This selector doesn't have any properties and will not be rendered.
  Error: Invalid CSS after ".morris-hover": expected selector, was "{position
  :absol..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using an `apply_to` parameter, I think you should explicitely remove the `sass` filter from your assetic stanza :

```
assetic:
    assets:
        main:
            inputs:
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/style.css
                - %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/sass/*
            output: 'css/main.css'
            filters:
                - cssrewrite
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        sass:
          bin: C:\Ruby21-x64\bin\sass
          apply_to: "\.scss$"
```

See this [issue](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic/issues/101) for instance

Comment: You are right ! I didn't find this issue but it works. I just fell uncomfortable with this because it looks like all hidden but thanks !